# How to hidden employee name duplicate sql

Tags: sql, mysql, plsql

i want to hide employee name from this

> [image: Blockquote]

To this

> [image: Blockquote]

Query

```
SELECT
XU.EMP_NAME,
XU.FUNCTION,
XU.ROLE_ACCESS 
FROM
XX_USERS XU LEFT JOIN 
XX_USERS_ACCESS XUA ON XU.EMP_ID=XUA.EMP_ID 
WHERE
NVL(XU.STATUS,'N')='Y'
order by  XU.EMP_NAME
```

its posible ?

Comment: what would be your logic to hide the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged the question with `PL/SQL` tag (which suggests that you might be using Oracle alongside `MySQL`), then: I don't have your tables, but I do have Scott's sample schema. Query that simulates what you have is:

```
SQL> select d.dname, e.ename, e.job
  2  from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  3  order by d.dname, e.ename;

DNAME          ENAME      JOB
-------------- ---------- ---------
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER
ACCOUNTING     KING       PRESIDENT
ACCOUNTING     MILLER     CLERK
RESEARCH       ADAMS      CLERK
RESEARCH       FORD       ANALYST
RESEARCH       JONES      MANAGER
RESEARCH       SCOTT      ANALYST
RESEARCH       SMITH      CLERK
SALES          ALLEN      SALESMAN
SALES          BLAKE      MANAGER
SALES          JAMES      CLERK
SALES          MARTIN     SALESMAN
SALES          TURNER     SALESMAN
SALES          WARD       SALESMAN

14 rows selected.
```

If you used SQL*Plus, you could set a `break`:

```
SQL> break on dname
SQL> /

DNAME          ENAME      JOB
-------------- ---------- ---------
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER
               KING       PRESIDENT
               MILLER     CLERK
RESEARCH       ADAMS      CLERK
               FORD       ANALYST
               JONES      MANAGER
               SCOTT      ANALYST
               SMITH      CLERK
SALES          ALLEN      SALESMAN
               BLAKE      MANAGER
               JAMES      CLERK
               MARTIN     SALESMAN
               TURNER     SALESMAN
               WARD       SALESMAN

14 rows selected.
```

Or, sort rows (using `row_number` analytic function) and conditionally display column value:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select d.dname, e.ename, e.job,
  3       row_number() over (partition by d.dname order by d.dname, e.ename) rn,
  4       row_number() over (order by d.dname, e.ename) rn_sort
  5     from emp e join dept d on d.deptno = e.deptno
  6    )
  7  select case when rn = 1 then dname else null end dname,
  8         ename, job
  9  from temp
 10  order by rn_sort;

DNAME          ENAME      JOB
-------------- ---------- ---------
ACCOUNTING     CLARK      MANAGER
               KING       PRESIDENT
               MILLER     CLERK
RESEARCH       ADAMS      CLERK
               FORD       ANALYST
               JONES      MANAGER
               SCOTT      ANALYST
               SMITH      CLERK
SALES          ALLEN      SALESMAN
               BLAKE      MANAGER
               JAMES      CLERK
               MARTIN     SALESMAN
               TURNER     SALESMAN
               WARD       SALESMAN

14 rows selected.
```

On the other hand, something like this is supposed to be used in some **reporting tool**, most (if not all) of them have such a "grouping" option. Usually, we don't do that in pure SQL.